# SignalR JWT authentication fails

Tags: c#, jwt, signalr, signalr.client

I'm trying to learn SignalR by creating a simple messaging app. The idea is that i have a public chat and private chat, and the private chat needs to have JWT authentication.

This project have a blazor server side rendered frontend and a RESTful api as backend.

As i understands the problem, it fails after backend have recvived information. In the first log its fails when getting response.

[image: Logs from console window]

JWT setup:

[image: JWT setup]
[image]

and Chat.Razor

[image: HubConnectionBuiolder]

Hub:

[image]

Debug level log:
[image]

Comment: Look at your server logs and see if they say anything about the error. Might need to enable debug level logging.

Comment: @Brennan I Think the problem is when server is returning the Negotiation to Client but im might be wrong. I have updated post with a new log if u want to give it a go. Im Currently researching about the Negotiations.

Comment: It looks like you have 2 servers, you need the logs for the other server. The one with port 44318.

Comment: I have found out what the problem was. In my JWT settings i had x.Authority = "Authority URL". When i disabled it, it worked.